# jQuery Sortable: helper option

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 sortable lists, let's say "modules" and "available-modules"

```
$(".available-modules").sortable({
    // helper: 'clone'
    // or
    helper: function(e, elt) {
        return elt.clone(true);
    }
})
```

None of this work: when I drop an item from "available-modules" to "modules", the item from "available-modules" is removed. I thought that using `helper: clone` would just insert the clone, not the actual item.

Is this my responsability to reinsert the element in the "available-modules" list after inserting it in the other one or is there a problem with my `helper` option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need something a bit like this demo:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

The drag "source" isn't sortable, just draggable, and makes use of the `connectToSortable` option.